# На самом деле - да

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?
1) Диалог: 
- Ты знал об этом раньше? 
- На самом деле - да. ( правильно ли поставлено тире и нужно ли брать слово  "да" в кавычки?) 
2) Это покажет время: стоит ли мне тебе доверять или нет. ( нужна ли перед "или" запятая?) 
3) Даже если всё это обойдём, для людоедов мы - всего лишь лёгкая добыча.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Диалог: 
— Ты знал об этом раньше? 
— На самом деле — да.**

На самом деле (= действительно, в действительности, фактически) — это наречное выражение.

Да — частица, утвердительный ответ на вопрос, поэтому кавычки не нужны. Сравнить: В ответ прозвучало твердое "да" (это сущ. ср. рода).

Тире интонационное, используется для лучшего понимания структуры предложения.

Из словаря:

1. **ДА, частица.** 1. Выражает согласие при ответе (противоп.: нет).  Мы где-то встречались? — Да, безусловно.

   Да, **неизм.; ср.** 1. Утвердительный ответ. Твёрдое, удивлённое, недоверчивое "да". Получить в ответ да. Ни да, ни нет не говорить, не отвечать (о стремлении избежать категоричности в ответе, уклониться от него).

2) ***Это покажет время: стоит ли мне тебе доверять или нет.***

***Это покажет время — стоит ли мне тебе доверять или нет.***

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным (частица ЛИ в роли подчинительного союза).

Сравнить: *Время покажет, стоит ли мне тебе доверять или нет.* Также: *Стоит ли мне тебе доверять или нет — **это** покажет время.*

В заданном предложении использована инверсия и в первой  части есть слово ***это*** , которое требует пояснения.

Пояснительные отношения можно обозначить двоеточием (или тире).

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=143#pp143

Запятая перед ИЛИ не ставится (используется правило для однородных членов для одиночного союза ИЛИ).

3) **Даже если всё это обойдём, для людоедов мы — всего лишь лёгкая добыча.**

Тире интонационное, обозначает паузу и определяет структуру предложения при инверсии.

Прямой порядок слов: Мы всего лишь легкая добыча для людоедов.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon